# Fatal Error-class mage

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, fatal-error, navigation

I wanted to show the subcategory images on the category pages. I was following the instructions from this [link](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html).

Somehow I either deleted something and now my website is bringing up a fatal error. I have several Magento sites so I tried numerous times to copy the `navigation.php` files from the other site into the error site but its not working. Can someone assist me with this?

the message I am receiving is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation' not found in
>   /home/public_html/app/code/community/Codnitive/Sidenav/Block/Navigation.php
>   on line 25

Answer (score 1):

This mean that Magento can't find this block !

1) Check if you have well declared your block in your **config.xml** like this:

```
<global>
    ...
    <blocks>
        <codnitive_sidenav>
            <class>Codnitive_Sidenav_Block</class>
        </codnitive_sidenav>
    </blocks>
    ...
</global>
```

2) Check the right path of **block** like this:

```
app/code/community/Codnitive/Sidenav/Block/Navigation.php
```

3) Clear your Magento cache.